# Using home cinema speakers with desktop audio interface

Tags: speakers, amplifier, cinema, home, matching

I would like to match four speakers left from an old Philips LX3600D home cinema system with my Komplete Audio 6 interface. When I test the levels with crocodile clips I get a very low intensity sound (checked with two different speakers and two different outputs).

According to the manuals I have these specs:
all four speakers have 4 Ohms impedance, and they've had an amplifier with 50 W power output,
and the interface is for 100 Ohms unbalanced, 200 Ohms balanced.
I guessed it should give enough power, since studio monitors work on higher levels and according to these answers: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90206/how-are-speakers-matched-with-audio-amplifiers-avoiding-overloading-either  I also thought impedance should be correct, but it's clear now, that I really don't understand it at all.

Can you suggest me a solution?
I know how to solder, and could make a DIY amp from a diagram with the parts given, if that would be a solution, I just don't know exactly what effect I am going for and what causes the problem.

Comment: You can find lots of diagrams online to build an amplifier. And many useful sites like this: http://www.gcaudio.com/resources/howtos/spkramp.html                            To help you decide on power needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably trying to connect passive speakers to line out level outputs, therefore the low acoustic level.

What you need is a four channels power amplifier with 4 ohms speakers outputs.

Comment: yeah, or active speakers/monitors instead.